# Finding elements in fluid container with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find the element corresponding to "Lønudvikling" to be able to click it on the following page: [SIRKA](https://www.krl.dk/#/sirka)

It is contained in a fluid container which may affect it somehow but I am not sure.

I've tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#launch url
url = "https://www.krl.dk/#/sirka/"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('udvikling')
```

Which is not right, since upon inspection I get the following html for that button:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-    class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
```

All the buttons are in a container as follows

```
<!-- ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapA">
        Lønniveau
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
      </div><!-- end ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
        Lønspredning
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
      </div><!-- end ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
        Lønudvikling
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
      </div><!-- end ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
```

Since id = r.id ? for all of them I am not sure how to find specific ones.

```
Særydelser
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
      </div><!-- end ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
        Antal ansatte
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
      </div><!-- end ngRepeat: r in reports | orderBy : 'order' --><div ng-repeat="r in reports | orderBy : 'order'" ng-class="reports[model.report].id == r.id ? 'sirkaRapA' : 'sirkaRapU clickable'" ng-click="chReport(r.id)" ng-show="show(r)" class="ng-binding ng-scope sirkaRapU clickable">
        Beskæftigelsesgrad
        Lønudvikling
        <!-- ngIf: r.help -->
</div>
```

So "udvikling" is only "shown" but not part of link as I understand it. 
I am also wondering if I am in the right window.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_link_text()` as well as `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` can be applied for links only (e.g. `<a href="#">Lønudvikling</a>`)

In your case you can use search by XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[normalize-space(.)="Lønudvikling"]')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(., "udvikling")]')
```